# How do I access the nth nested list, were I know the depth of nested lists?

Tags: python, tree, nested-lists, depth

In a general case I'm classifying data points in nested lists with variable depths of nested loops, for example in a simple case :

```
alist = [ [[a, b], [c, d]],  [[e, f], [g, h]] ]
```

I use this to have operations like brackets, for example :

```
min ([ max([a, b]), max([c,d]) ])
```

However the problem I encounter is that in my example I reference [a, b] and [c, d], but I want to reference these as variables or indexes of a list in the case were we have a known depth of nested lists and known number of elements in the deepest nested brackets.

With what I know about using list indexes, I don't see how I can reference a **n**<sup>th</sup> depth in a nested list. If I wanted to reference the third nested list I have to explicitly write:

```
nlist[0][0][i]
```

And therefore if the depth varies, I can't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to know more than just the depth. Like in your final example, you need to have 3 values: 0, 0, i.

In the generic case you would need to know *n* indices.

So you could write a little helper function that takes those indices as argument:

```
def deep_get(lst, *indices):
    for i in indices:
        lst = lst[i]
    return lst
```

And now when you have a list `indices` you can do:

```
indices = [0, 0, i]
# ...
# ...
print(deep_get(lst, *indices))
```

### Setting

If you need to *set* a value instead of *getting* it, then use this function:

```
def deep_set(lst, value, *indices):
    for i in indices[:-1]:
        lst = lst[i]
    lst[indices[-1]] = value
```

Call as:

```
indices = [0, 0, i]
# ...
# ...
newValue = 9
print(deep_set(lst, newValue, *indices))
```

Comment: What if instead of pulling or getting a list with the index i want to assign a value at an index like : `indices = [0, 0, 1]`

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: A clean solution!  But I'm puzzled by the way lists behave as arguments. Line 4 of the deep_set function modifies lst also in the caller's scope -- fine since lists are mutable and they are passed by reference.But why doesn't line 3 also change lst? I experimented a bit and I've seen that changes made in a fn to elements of a list passed as an argument are preserved in the caller's scope, but any changes of the kind "lst = lst[n]" aren't. This seems to me a very smart feature, but the "=" does not so much act as an assignment operator, it's rather a means for focusing onto a sublist.

Comment: The `=` operator is an assignment. The assignment to a (local) name (`lst`) does not mutate anything. However, after that assignment, `lst` still references an object in the caller's nested structure, so that the final assignment to a list subscript **does** impact the caller's structure. There is a huge difference between assignment to a **name** and assignment to an **attribute** or **subscription** or **slice**. The first does not mutate an object, the latter can perform mutation. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)